# Change columns in datagrid

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I work with a winform application.
I want to change the place of two columns with eachother in a datagridview.
For example I have a datagridview with two column that first column1 is showing and then column2 is showing.And now I want to show column2 and then column1.
How to I do this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set the `DisplayIndex` of the Column

```
dataGridView1.Columns["FirstColumnName"].DisplayIndex = 1;
```

this will display the column as second column

Comment: Any chance you can give a example for this in MVVM ?

Comment: r u using WPF / Winforms. if WPF, is it DataGridView or a WPF GridView

Comment: I'd like to use this in a Silverlight / C# application using MVVM and no code behind.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do something like this:

```
DataTable dt=new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Column2");
dt.Columns.Add("Column1");
DataRow dr=dt.NewRow();
dr["Column2"]="";
dr["Column1"]="";
dt.Rows.Add(dr);
yourDatagrid.DataSource=dt;
YourDatagrid.DataBind();
```